# Vuejs variable visibility in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

I'm using vue socket.io https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io I want to use the information I receive to update the location but it seems is not accessible from this scope. How can I access it and update.

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
 , data () {
    return {
      location: {lat:10, lng:10}
    }
  },sockets: {
    connect: ()=> {
      console.log('socket connected')
    }
    location: (val) => {
      this.location = val // how can I update location. it is not accessible here
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: from https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods , `Note that you should not use an arrow function to define a method (e.g. plus: () => this.a++). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.a will be undefined.`

Comment: Also, you can change the name of location object

Comment: @JacobGoh Thanks it resolve my issue. regards